# What is the purpose of low and high nibble when converting a string to a HexString

Tags: java, md5, nibble

Recently I have been going through some examples of MD5 to start getting an understanding of security and MD5 has been fairly simple to understand for the most part and a good starting point even though it is no longer secure. Despite this I have a question regarding high and lo nibbles when it comes to converting a string to a hex string.

So I know high and low nibbles are equal to half a byte or also can be hex digits that represent a single hexadecimal digit. What I am not understanding though is exactly how they work and the purpose that they serve. I have been searching on google and I can't find much of an answer that will help explain what they do in the context that they are in. Here is the context of the conversion:

```
private static String toHexString( byte[] byteArray )
    {
        final String HEX_CHARS = "0123456789ABCDEF"; 

        byte[] result = new byte[byteArray.length << 1];
        int len = byteArray.length;
        for( int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++ )
        {
            byte b = byteArray[i]
            int lo4 = b & 0x0F;
            int hi4 = ( b & 0xF0 ) >> 4;


            result[i * 2] = (byte)HEX_CHARS.charAt( hi4 );
            result[i * 2 + 1] = (byte)HEX_CHARS.charAt( lo4 );
        }
        return new String( result );
    }
```

I don't exactly understand what is going on in the for statement. I would appreciate any help understanding this and if there is some link to some places that I can learn more about this please also leave it.

I understand the base definition of nibble but not the operations and what the assignment to the number 4 is doing either.

If I need to post the full example code I will just ask as I am unsure if it is needed.

Comment: Exactly which part do you have a problem with?

Comment: @lexicore not exactly a problem but as stated above I understand what high and low nibbles are but I do not understand what there purpose and how they work in this example.

Comment: @lexicore I only understand the definition not the usage and in order to use MD5 and do something with it I need to understand it first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding hexadecimals and bytes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081523/understanding-hexadecimals-and-bytes-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Progman that post does not answer my question at all it has nothing to do with high and low bytes and their usage or anything as far as I can see

Comment: @Progman Edit to my last comment the post has nothing to do with the purpose of high and low bits and their usage which I explicitly put in the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code simply converts a byte array to hexadecimal representation. Within the `for`-loop, each byte is converted into two characters. I think it's easier to understand it on an example.

Assume one of the bytes in your array is, say, `218` (unsigned). That's `1101 1010` in binary.

`lo4` gets the lowest 4 bits by AND-ing the byte with the bitmask `00001111`:

```
int lo4 = b & 0x0F;
```

This results in `1010`, `10` in decimal.

`hi4` gets the highest 4 bits by AND-ing with the bitmask `1111 0000` and shifting 4 bits to the right:

```
int hi4 = ( b & 0xF0 ) >> 4;
```

This results in `1101`, `13` in decimal.

Now to get the hexadecimal representation of this byte you only need to convert `10` and `13` to their hexadecimal representations and concatenate. For this you simply look up the character in the prepared `HEX_CHARS` string at the specific index. `10` -> `A`, `13` -> `D`, resulting in `218` -> `DA`.

Answer (score 1):

It's just bit operations. The & character takes the literal bit value of each and does a logical and on them.

```
int lo4 = b & 0x0F;
```

for instance if b = 24 then it will evaluate to this

```
 00011000
+00001111
=00001000
```

The second such line does the same on the first four bits.

```
 00011000
+11110000
=00010000
```

the '>>' shifts all of the bits a certain number in that direction so

```
00010000 >> 4 = 00000001.
```

This is done so that you can derive the hex value from the number. Since each character in hex can represent 4 bits by splitting the number into pieces of 4 bits we can convert it.

in the case of b = 24 we no have lo4 = 1000 or 8 and hi4 = 0001 or 1. The last part of the loop assigns the character value for each.

Hex_chars[hi4] = '1' and Hex_chars[lo4] = '8' which gives you "18" for that part of the string which is 24 in hex.